# saving entities with many to one relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following entities

```
@Entity
public class Session{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="session_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private List<SessionChart> sessionCharts;

    public List<SessionChart> getSessionCharts() {
        return sessionCharts;
    }

    public void setSessionCharts(List<SessionChart> sessionCharts) {
        this.sessionCharts = sessionCharts;
    }
}
```

and an entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="session_chart")
public class SessionChart implements  {



    @Transient
    private boolean isActive = false;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String chartName;
}
```

suppose i have retrieved my sessioncharts from a specific session

```
List<SessionChart> mySessionCharts = new ArrayList<SessionChart>();
mySessionCharts = session.getSessionCharts();
```

and in my code I change the name of one `sessionChart`. If I save the session(merge) entity then the `sessionCharts ArrayList` will be updated. My question is the following:

Can I save just the `SessionChart` object from the list without saving the session? Will it work if i delete a session chart and just remove it from the ArrayList?

I am using jpa hibernate and `EntityManager` and `EntityManagerFactory` to do the database transactions.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I save just the SessionChart object from the list without saving the session?

Yes, that is possible as long as the entities are still managed and your transaction is still alive. So this code will work:

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
Session session = em.find(Session.class, 1);
List<SessionChart> mySessionCharts = session.getSessionCharts();
for (SessionChart sessionChart : mySessionCharts) {
    sessionChart.setChartName("test"); // this will update each session chart name in the DB
}
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

> Will it work if i delete a session chart and just remove it from the ArrayList?

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but here's the thing: if you just remove just the `SessionChart` object from the collections object, then call on `em.merge(session)`, this will just unlink the `SessionChart` object from its parent `Session`. Example below:

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
Session session = em.find(Session.class, 1);
List<SessionChart> sessionChartList = session.getSessionCharts();
sessionChartList.remove(0); // remove the first object from the list
em.merge(session);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

This will result to an SQL update on the session_chart table:

```
update
    session_chart 
set
    session_id=null 
where
    session_id=1
    and id=1
```

You still have to invoke `em.remove(sessionChart)` to explicitly remove it from the DB.

Comment: I was thinking If I could just do em.remove(sessionChart) and that would update the session entity as well. But I guess it doesn't

Comment: If you invoke em.remove(sessionChart), the collections object that is in memory will not be updated. So if you iterate the sessionChart objects from the list, you will still be able to reference the one removed from the DB, because that object stays in memory. 

However, if you try to load again the session object from the DB through em.find() or any query, you'll get an updated list of sessionChart objects.